# Password Text box getting cleared on selecting dropdown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have problem with password text box control. I have username textbox, password textbox, retypepassword textbox. And i have drowpdownlist with items Website, Newspaper, Others. After filling username, password, retype password in textbox. Whenever i am selecting items Newspaper and Others items from drowdownlist, password and retypepassword textbox value getting cleared. I have set in autopostback=true in dropdownlist control. Pls somebody help me where is my mistake??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting autopostback = false.

Comment: There are many ways to fix this. you can do autopostback=false if it is not intended, you can separate out them in two different update panels, that will prevent it from refreshing. you can use pure/jquery ajax in place of full postback in dropdown change event.

Answer (score 2):

This is by intention since the `AutoPostBack` is set to `True`, the website will perform a post back and reload the page (or partial page). Values in password inputs are not preserved during `Postbacks`.